# How to calculate button width

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create dynamic matrix of buttons - e.g. 5x6 on large devices and 4x5 on smaller devices. And I want to take into consideration applied style as well (textSize, padding ..) I am able to load font size and calculate neccessary space for button text. But there is much more space needed.

I am performing this task in `onGlobalLayout` method because there I get container dimensions. Maybe to create sample Button and simulate its layout?

Comment: You could set the layout_width to 0dp and use layout_weight=1, have you tried this yet?

Comment: I don't like onGlobalLayout, sometimes trigger and I don't know why lol. So I do a customView and override the onSizeChanged method.

Comment: @vilpe89 This is not relevant. I need to calculate if there will be three or four buttons per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged into `ViewGroup` and layout procedure and this is the result:

```
Button button = inflateButton();
button.setText(logic.getText());
button.measure(500, 500);
int tileWidth = button.getMeasuredWidth();
```